# OpenLayers Map Draw polygon Feature inside boundaries

Tags: openlayers, geometry

Is it possible to draw polygon inside specific boundaries?

```
draw_interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vector_layer.getSource(),
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ($geom_type.val())
});

map.addInteraction(draw_interaction);
```

Specify boundaries area in yellow is it possible to add new Geometry Type inside yellow area only? https://jsfiddle.net/vishal05/wb3m90eb/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ol.geom.Point#getCoordinates()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Point.html#getCoordinates) and [`ol.geom.Polygon#intersectsCoordinate(coordinate)`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#intersectsCoordinate) methods together.

I changed your code like this:

```
function addDrawInteraction() {
    // remove other interactions
    map.removeInteraction(select_interaction);
    map.removeInteraction(modify_interaction);

    // create the interaction
    draw_interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: vector_layer.getSource(),
        type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ($geom_type.val())
    });
    // add it to the map
    map.addInteraction(draw_interaction);
    var isInsideThePolygon=true;
    // when a new feature has been drawn...
    draw_interaction.on('drawend', function(event) {
            if(isInsideThePolygon){
          // create a unique id
          // it is later needed to delete features
          var id = uid();
          // give the feature this id
          event.feature.setId(id);
          // save the changed data
          saveData();
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(function(){
            vector_layer.getSource().removeFeature(event.feature);
          }, 10
          );
        }
    });

    draw_interaction.on('drawstart', function(event) {        
        var drawnPointCoordinates= event.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        var polyGeometry=polyFeature.getGeometry();
        isInsideThePolygon=polyGeometry.intersectsCoordinate(drawnPointCoordinates);       
    });

}
```

[New JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/himyata/u5sq1wh8/)

Comment: it is give me error like this "addrawInteraction() function is not define" on change Geometry type

Comment: Could you run my jsFiddle link?

Comment: Yes intersectsCoordinate method is only used with openlayer 4.0.1 and above and my version is 3.6.1 is theri any possiblity to used in 3.6.1?

Comment: What about update your version?

Comment: Their are so many method is deprecated in OpenLayer 4.0.1 so is their any possibility to use intersectsCoordinate method inside 3.6.1?